# File transfer to Android

Tags: linux, android

I am using Linux Mint 19 as my Operating System. I would like to transfer file to Android phone from my computer (Linux Mint 19.1). How can I do that ?

Comment: There are several ways: `adb`, `SSH`, `MTP` (it only works with a cable I think).

Comment: Also FTP (my preferred way), bluetooth, AirDroid.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, how to use those ?

Comment: @ajgringo619  , how to use those ?

Answer (score 2):

With standard apps:

- If you have Bluetooth available on both sides, establish the connection and send by Bluetooth (mostly for small/medium files, because transfer rate isn't very fast...)
- With a USB cable between the two: on connection the Android phone will ask what to do (besides charging): connect as PTP (Photo transfer) or MTP (general file transfer). If you pick one these two the phone should appear in your file manager (at least it does for me: KDE+Dolphin on Kubuntu 16.04). Transfer is much faster than with Bluetooth.

If you have a cloud box (Dropbox or else), you can also use it to share files between the two.

Comment: +1, this is **the** solution. No extra software required, relies on built-in, standard solution.

Comment: Thanks @xenoid. I am not getting this `on connection the Android phone will ask what to do (besides charging): connect as PTP (Photo transfer) or MTP (general file transfer)`. I am not getting this `the phone should appear in your file manager`. I am using Linux Mint 19.1 and I am using Redmi Android Phone. Thanks.

Comment: @gronostaj WiFi is more than 10x faster than Bluetooth, so it can't be so readily dismissed, especially when some new phones have internal storage of 512+ GB. The speed of the connection is one of the most important factors to consider. Bluetooth is almost a novelty in comparison.

Comment: @wrecclesham Wi-Fi should be considered as an option, but it requires additional software and configuration. I think built-in features should be preferred unless they turn up insufficient for the task.

Comment: @gronostaj, I can't use xenoid solution.

Answer (score 1):

1) Install a free Android app called Sweech on your smartphone:

[image]

2) Ensure that both your Linux device and cell phone are connected to the same network (i.e. same WiFi etc.)

3) Click on the play icon in the Sweech app to enabling sharing from your cell phone:

[image]

4) Open any web browser on your Linux device and browse to the web address shown in the Sweech app, including the port number:

[image]

You can now access your cell phone's files from your Linux device over WiFi, using your home wireless network.

Sweech provides:

- remote read access to your smartphone
- remote write access to your smartphone

However:

- Sweech does *not* allow you to remotely delete files on your smartphone from another device. This is the only real limitation I've seen with this app, it's otherwise excellent.

Comment: Thanks @wrecclesham. I have no wifi. I would like to use Cable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do it thorugh USB .
Connect your android thorugh USB cable to the system(Computer)and turn on the file transfer in your handset.
It will generate a location of your android data in your computer .And that's it.
It's easy and fast .

Comment: @xenoid's answer already contains this suggestion

Comment: Thanks @Da3kL10rd. How to do this `turn on the file transfer in your handset` ?

Comment: @abuabu when u connect ur phone . Automatically a notification will pop up . something like "Usb is charging this device ." Click on the notification . There will be an option for file transfer . Select it and U r Good to go .

Comment: @Da3kL10rd thanks for your reply. I am not getting any thing like this. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu What's the model of your phone???

Comment: It is a Redmi Phone.

Comment: @abuabu Then there must be a option .

Comment: @Da3kL10rd, I have 2 phone, 1 is displaying the option and another is not showing the option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- set-up a samba shared folder on your Mint system, [this post explains it in detail](https://www.technig.com/share-files-via-linux-mint-to-windows-10/) . (Remember to open samba and, samba-client protocols in your firewall if enabled).
- Then from your Android device, you can merely use a file manager with network devices capability (e.g. ES File Explorer), so you should discover the shared folder on your Local Network, and then copy/move files between directories.

Answer (score 1):

Just use USB or Bluetooth. You can probably also set up a google drive for secure file transfer.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWorks. I tried USB but failed. Thanks.

Comment: make sure that it is using USB in file transfer mode

Comment: How to enable file transfer mode ?

Comment: Unlock your Android device.
With a USB cable, connect your device to your computer.
On your device, tap the "Charging this device via USB" notification.
Under "Use USB for," select File Transfer.
A file transfer window will open on your computer. Use it to drag files.
When you're done, eject your device from Windows.
Unplug the USB cable.

Comment: I am using Redmi Phone. I am not getting  "Charging this device via USB". When I connect to my Linux Mint 19.1 laptop it starts charging. Thanks.

Comment: try and install the adb and fastboot drivers, that might install the USB drivers.

Comment: @JosephWorks,  Where and how should I install adb and fastboot drivers ?

Comment: On Linux, use sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot